# C# - contains throws null exception

Tags: c#

My code

```
 string? SegroupOf;

 if(SegroupOf.Contains("Team"))
 {
    
 }
```

If SegroupOf is null it throws an error. How to handle null? I have given SegroupOf as nullable, how to make sure even if its null it doesnot throw any error

Comment: `if(SegroupOf?.Contains("Team") == true)` for example

Comment: I get this error cannot convert bool? to bool

Comment: works fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hY9Wvi

Comment: you can also use "conditional-operator"  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SegroupOf) ? false : SegroupOf.Contains("Team"))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [null-conditional-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) like so:

```
if(SegroupOf?.Contains("Team") == true)
```

However as `SegroupOf?.Contains` returns a `bool?` instead of `bool`, you need to compare the result to the `bool`-value `true`.

You can also just use old-school null-check:

```
if(Segroup != null && Segroup.Contains("Team"))
```

However that is slightly different as the null-conditional is short-circuiting, meaning `Segroup` is only accessed once, while in the second case it's accessed two times.

Comment: whats the difference between if(SegroupOf?.Contains("Team") == true) and if(SegroupOf?.Contains("Team"))

Comment: @Venkat the latter doesn't compile, because `?Contains` returns a nullable `bool` , not a "normal" `bool`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the code generated for `if (x?.Contains(y) == true)` is *significantly* longer than that generated for `if (x != null && x.Contains(y))`. This is rarely significant, but if you're calling this in a tight loop and performance is an issue, you should bear this in mind.

Comment: @MatthewWatson that's why I mentioned that in my last paragraph. Slightly and signifanctly are pretty opinion-based term, though.

Comment: Actually yes, I take that back: I accidentally used `if(SegroupOf?.Contains("Team") is true)` rather than `if(SegroupOf?.Contains("Team") == true)` in my test - which of course does make a big difference, as [demonstrated here on sharp.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKEIwGYACDHANgqzIBUBTAZwUIG9CzuLzKbgAe0EoGLBDgAUlAAwB+MswCUXHpwI9NFAOyK5AOgDCgmAmgxmkgERMIYK0rIBeJ2QQAnAK6MA3Ku4AvoT+vBTUZEIiYqxY0jjyiioaaiGaGLrMZACErjCeKKIAZIWKRiZmsJY2jHYOfsmBwQ2h/BHCokysJHEJyiHqWjzpemWm5lW29o5QmR7e9ZpBBEtAA) - so yes `== true` is fine!

Comment: In fact, looking at the assembler output from the jitter (on sharp.io) the two methods are pretty much identical in efficiency.